# When I run $ rails new testapp I get a bad interpreter

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, homebrew, rbenv

I am trying to get my development environment up and running and I hit a major snag. Everything looked like it would be a big success and instead I got a bad interpreter. Can anyone help me with this?

These are the return values I get when I run them at the command line:

```
command: `$ xcode-select version` returns: `2343.`
command: `$ rbenv version` returns: `rbenv 1.0.0`
command: `$ rbenv global 2.2.1` set rbenv to *2.2.1
command: `$ ruby -v` returns: `2.2.1p85`
```

Okay so far...

```
command: `$ gem install rails` returned: `Successfully installed rails-4.2.6`
command: `$ rbenv rehash` after every command
command: `$ rails new testapp` returns: `-bash: /usr/local/bin/rails: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`
```

I think I have a problem.

```
command: `$ git --version` returns: `git version 2.5.4`
```

What might be going on and can I recover from such a fall?

When I start the server and look at the url I see versions of rail there.

```
command: `$ gem server`
```

at the url localhost:8808 I see 3 gems versions of rails there: 4.2.4, 4.2.5, 4.2.6

How do I resolve this?

Comment: What does   which ruby show ?

Comment: `$ 2.2.1p85` returns `ruby 2.2.1p85`

Comment: rails has `/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby` as its shebang (#!),   but that doesn't appear to exist. if `which ruby` doesn't return something and requires you to type `2.2.1p85` in order to execute it something it messed up.  I'm not an rbenv user (still prefer rvm), but that appears that either your rbenv install ins messed up, or you are installing rails with a different version of ruby then you are trying to run it with.  gem will normally set the shebang to the current running version of ruby.

Comment: This is the state of my .bash_profile:

Comment: This is the state of my .bash_profile:
    `source ~/.profile`
     ### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
    `export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"`
    `export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"`

    `alias ll="ls -AlFahG"`

    `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"`


    `export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"`
    `eval "$(rbenv init -)"`
    `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

    `export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin`
    `export EDITOR="atom -w"`

Answer (score 1):

try to cleanup with `gem cleanup` and then reinstall `rails`

`gem uninstall rails`

`gem install rails`

Comment: I performed these 3 commands and nothing changed. I think my problem is in

Comment: I performed these 3 commands and nothing changed. I think the problem is with the bash shell at this point. The `$ gem cleanup` worked, the `$gem uninstall rails, worked and the `$gem install rails` installed `rails 4.2.6`, but after I ran `rbenv rehash`, closed the terminal application and reopened it, the return from `$ rails -v` was and continues to be `-bash: /usr/local/bin/rails: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`. I can post the contents of my .bash_profile if that could help.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR: Trash all of the ruby-related, non-symlink scripts in /usr/local/bin, i.e. everything with that broken shebang.**

I was writing up an answer when I realized that @Doon hit it on the head, deep in his comment on the question:

> gem will normally set the shebang to the current running version of ruby.

I ran into this "bad interpreter" error after setting up a new dev laptop.  I had initially installed ruby via Homebrew (`brew install ruby`) just to get up-and-running quickly.  A corporate setup script had installed chruby, however I don't think it built any rubies.  Presumably I also installed some gems.  I then installed rbenv, which I'm used to and comfortable with, and using it, I installed a couple rubies.  At some point I uninstalled Homebrew's ruby and chruby.

By that point, I had several executables in `/usr/local/bin/` which were regular files (i.e. *not* symlinks to files in `../Cellar`), all of which had a shebang line of `#!/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby`.  However, `/usr/local/opt/ruby` had been deleted when I uninstalled Homebrew's ruby, leading to all these broken scripts.

**My Solution: Start from scratch!**

1. Uninstall the rbenv-built rubies (`rbenv uninstall 1.2.3`)
2. Trash all of the ruby-related, non-symlink scripts in /usr/local/bin.  i.e. everything with that broken shebang
3. Re-install the rbenv rubies

Note: that broke Homebrew's vim, which requires the ruby bottle, so I reinstalled it.

The gem-based scripts in /usr/local/bin are now symlinks into Cellar, with a Cellar-based shebang, and my project-specific rbenv-installed rubies point into my .rbenv folder.   All sees to be well!

Answer (score 1):

Install rails to the mentioned location. It should work then.

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin/ rails
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for ages.

Answer (score 0):

Bijoy Thangaraj's answer has helped solve the problem in my case. My intention was to add this text as a comment, but given that I have less than 50 reputation it's not possible.

If it can be converted to a comment under the relevant answer it would be appreciated.

I tried installing via rbenv , rvm and the source code. I am focusing on the process via the source code because the bash doesn't scroll any further up after a point.

If you are not interested in following my process, please feel free to jump straight to step f) which is directly related to the main thread of this page.

a) I followed the guide found at [gorails.com: Install Ruby On Rails on
Windows 10 Guide](https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10#ruby),

b) particularly followed these steps [installing ruby on rails via source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5o4w.png)

c) After typing the last command `:~/ruby-2.7.1$ ruby -v`,

I got: `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]`.

Still version 2.3.

d) However, I typed in the next command suggested by [gorails.com - Install Ruby on Rails on Windows 10 Guide](https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10#ruby). command `$ gem install bundler`,

I got: `Fetching bundler-2.1.4.gem
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0 directory.`

Tried with `$ sudo gem install bundler` and

got: `Fetching bundler-2.1.4.gem
Successfully installed bundler-2.1.4
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.1.4
Installing ri documentation for bundler-2.1.4
Done installing documentation for bundler after 15 seconds
1 gem installed`.

e) Following on on the same guide, then typed in `$ gem install rails -v 6.0.2.2`

after some fetching happened, I eventually got: `Fetching sprockets-rails-3.2.1.gem
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0 directory.`

Also, checking the rails version:

command: `$ rails -v`

result: `Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from /mnt/c/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/rails:22:in`'
        1: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:252:in `bin_path'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:275:in`find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem railties (>= 0.a) with executable rails (Gem::GemNotFoundException)`.

Checking ruby version:

command: `$ ruby -v`

result: `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]`

f) Carried on to install rails:

command: `sudo gem install rails`

result; `Done installing documentation for concurrent-ruby, i18n, thread_safe, tzinfo, zeitwerk, activesupport, rack, rack-test, mini_portile2, nokogiri, crass, loofah, rails-html-sanitizer, rails-dom-testing, builder, erubi, actionview, actionpack, activemodel, activerecord, globalid, activejob, mini_mime, mail, actionmailer, nio4r, websocket-extensions, websocket-driver, actioncable, mimemagic, marcel, activestorage, actionmailbox, actiontext, thor, method_source, railties, sprockets, sprockets-rails, rails after 1268 seconds
40 gems installed`

Checking the rails version:

command: `$ rails -v`

result: `bash: /mnt/c/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/rails: ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`.

Finally,

g) command: `$ sudo gem install -n /mnt/c/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/ rails`
   result: `Successfully installed rails-6.0.2.2
Parsing documentation for rails-6.0.2.2
Done installing documentation for rails after 0 seconds
1 gem installed`

Checking the rails version:

Command: `rails -v`

Result: `Rails 6.0.2.2`

Checking Ruby version:

Command: `ruby -v`

Result: `ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-linux]`